# ASP MVC ClosedXML Set radiobutton in excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, radio-button, closedxml

I am using the ClosedXML NuGet Package to edit an existing excel file. I can edit cells with just text but there is also a radio button field for Gender.

How can I set these radio buttons?

**Example for setting text :**

sheet.Cells("F14").Value = "Text"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported in ClosedXML yet.

Comment: Damn, do you have any alternative I can use?